# How to control the update on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, ienumerable

If I have a method with the following signature:

```
public IEnumerable<ScheduleDetailsView> StructureSchedule()
    {
        bool isStartWeek = false;
        int index = -1;
        var week = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Week)).Cast<Week>();
        var weekLength = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Week)).Length;
        List<ScheduleDetailsView> scheduleDetailsViews = new List<ScheduleDetailsView>();
        for (int i = 0; i < weekLength; i++)
        {
            if (isStartWeek)
            {
                if (WorkingGroup.WeekStart == week.ElementAt(i))
                {
                    index = i;
                    i = 0;
                    isStartWeek = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScheduleDetailsView scheduleDetailsView = new ScheduleDetailsView(i, week.ElementAt((i + index) % weekLength), false, false,0);
                scheduleDetailsViews.Add(scheduleDetailsView);
            }
        }
        return scheduleDetailsViews;
    }
```

---

```
public class ScheduleDetailView
    {
        public ScheduleDetailView(int id, Week workingDay, bool isWeekend, bool isShortDay, int order, int shiftId)
        {
            Id = id;
            WorkingDay = workingDay;
            IsWeekend = isWeekend;
            IsShortDay = isShortDay;
            this.order = order;
            ShiftId = shiftId;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Week WorkingDay { get; set; }
        public bool IsWeekend { get; set; }
        public bool IsShortDay { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public int ShiftId { get; set; }
        public Shift Shift { get; set; }

    }
```

---

Now the user of this method should fill only some properties in this structure`(IsWeekend ,IsShortDay ,ShiftId )` without adding new ScheduleDetailView or Changing the order of these items or override the whole
`IEnumerable` and return it back to the caller.

EX:

```
id  WorkingDay    IsWeekend  IsShortDay   order  ShiftId 
1     6            false      false         1      -1
2     7            false      false         2      -1
3     1            false      false         3      -1
4     2            false      false         4      -1
5     3            false      false         5      -1
6     4            false      false         6      -1
7     5            false      false         7      -1
```

---

**This is accepted :**

```
1     6            true       false         1      -1
2     7            false      false         2      -1
3     1            false      false         3      -1
4     2            false      false         4      -1
5     3            false      false         5      -1
6     4            false      false         6      -1
7     5            true       true          7      -1
```

---

**This is not allowed :** because it changes `WorkingDay`

```
1     5            true       false         1      -1
2     7            false      false         2      -1
3     1            false      false         3      -1
4     2            false      false         4      -1
5     3            false      false         5      -1
6     4            false      false         6      -1
7     6            true       true          7      -1
```

---

**This is not allowed :** because it deletes from the returned IEnum

```
1     6            true       false         1      -1
2     7            false      false         2      -1
3     1            false      false         3      -1
4     2            false      false         4      -1
5     3            false      false         5      -1
6     4            false      false         6      -1
```

How to guarantee that the user of this method will just update  `(IsWeekend ,IsShortDay ,ShiftId )` in the previous structure and return the IEnumerable in its updated version.

Comment: What do you mean by "override the whole IEnumerable"? `IEnumerable` cannot be changed, reordered etc by it's interface. You can only cast it back to concrete type like `List` (if it was List) and change it but this would be a violation of an interface

Comment: I mean some thing like that :
`IEnumerable<ScheduleDetailView> x = new List <ScheduleDetailView>();`

Comment: Do you want to create an `IEnumerable` which cannot be changed even with casting or do you want to receive back only the `IEnumerable` created inside `StructureSchedule` and not any created outside this method?

Comment: @arekzyla `I want to receive back only the IEnumerable created inside StructureSchedule and not any created outside this method` exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want this kind of separation you are talking about 2 subsystems. At least logically, they may be in the same process for now.

To get a proper isolation use a DTO (Data Transfer Object). That could be the same class but it requires different instances. The consumer should return an updated list of items and then you copy *only* the relevan properties back to the original items.

Comment: Could you explain more please

Comment: I just expose a view but I want to validate the returned back against my business rules. for example the count of objects is = 7 ( a week) so I don't want the user to add new objects to the list.

Comment: They are not 2 subsystems, there’s  the domain classes and the mvc web application which uses the domain classes, and i want to put more control on the methods used by the mvc developers

Comment: I would call that 2 susbsystems. There is no magic wand here, validate your data on every doorstep.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I’m sorry if I bothered you, I just wanna to do it in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define an interface to expose a subset of `ScheduleDetailView`
2. Make `ScheduleDetailView` `internal` so other assemblies couldn't downcast to the full type.
3. Use [`ImmutableSortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467193(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare So make a tinier subset! What's the issue with this? There's no magical solution for your problem: you need to segregate your surface based on your requirement.